# Error MethodNotallowedHttpException Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I m trying to save the same data to DB:

My form code

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'dashboard.settings.general.save','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST','files'=>true]) !!}

                    {{-- {{ csrf_field() }} --}}
              
             

                    <div class="box-body">

                        @if ($errors->any())

                            <div class="alert alert-danger">

                                <ul>

                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

                                        <li>{!! $error !!}</li>

                                    @endforeach

                                </ul>

                            </div>

                        @endif

                        <h4>{{__('General')}}</h4>

                        <div class="form-group row {{$errors->has('title')? 'has-danger':''}}">

                            {{Form::label('title',__("Title"),['class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label' ])}}

                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                {!!Form::text('title',setting('general.title'),['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'title'])!!}

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My Routes file

```
  Route::middleware(['auth'])->prefix('dashboard')->name('dashboard.')->group(function () {        
        Route::get('settings/general','SettingsController@index')->name('settings.general');   
        Route::post('settings/general/save','SettingsController@setGeneral')->name('settings.general.save');  
});
```

it's been more than 3 hours with that error, any help,
I'm trying a lot of solutions but no one of theme work perfectly,
any help I can't progress my work with that problem

[image]

Comment: `'method'=>'POST'` missing in `Form::open`

Comment: there is, par default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oooooh ops: the problem was textarea control form

```
{{-- {!!Form::textarea('pixel',setting('seo.pixel'),['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'pixel'])!!} --}}
```

in it, I'm trying to echo their DB content